# How can I calculate histograms with merged bins?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I want to ask you about calculating the histogram in Python using OpenCV. I used this code:

```py
hist = cv2.calcHist(im, [0, 1, 2], None, [8, 8, 8], [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
```

The result gave me the histogram of each color channel with 8 bins, but what I want to get is:

- 1st bin (**R=0-32,G=0-32,B=0-32**),
- 2nd bin (**R=33-64,G=0-32,B=0-32**),
- and so on,

so I will have 512 bins in total.

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting my question

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, your `cv2.calcHist` call isn't correct:

```py
hist = cv2.calcHist(im, [0, 1, 2], None, [8, 8, 8], [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
```

The first parameter should be a list of images:

```py
hist = cv2.calcHist([im], [0, 1, 2], None, [8, 8, 8], [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
```

Let's see this small example:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Red blue square of size [4, 4], i.e. eight pixels (255, 0, 0) and eight pixels (0, 0, 255); Attention: BGR ordering!
image = np.zeros((4, 4, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
image[:, 0:2, 2] = 255
image[:, 2:4, 0] = 255

# Calculate histogram with two bins [0 - 127] and [128 - 255] per channel:
# Result should be hist["bin 0", "bin 0", "bin 1"] = 8 (red) and hist["bin 1", "bin 0", "bin 0"] = 8 (blue)

# Original cv2.calcHist call with two  bins [0 - 127] and [128 - 255]
hist = cv2.calcHist(image, [0, 1, 2], None, [2, 2, 2], [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
print(hist, '\n')       # Not correct

# Correct cv2.calcHist call
hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [0, 1, 2], None, [2, 2, 2], [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
print(hist, '\n')       # Correct
```

```
[[[8. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0.]
  [0. 4.]]] 

[[[0. 8.]
  [0. 0.]]

 [[8. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]]
```

As you can, your version only has 12 values in total, whereas there are 16 pixels in the image! Also, it's not clear, what "bins" (if at all) are represented.

So, having the proper `cv2.calcHist` call, your general idea/approach is correct! Maybe, you just need a little hint, "how to read" the resuling `hist`:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Colored rectangle of size [32, 16] with one "color" per bin for eight bins per channel,
# i.e. 512 pixels, such that each of the resulting 512 bins has value 1
x = np.linspace(16, 240, 8, dtype=np.uint8)
image = np.reshape(np.moveaxis(np.array(np.meshgrid(x, x, x)), [0, 1, 2, 3], [3, 0, 1, 2]), (32, 16, 3))

# Correct cv2.calcHist call
hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [0, 1, 2], None, [8, 8, 8], [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])

# Lengthy output of each histogram bin
for B in np.arange(hist.shape[0]):
    for G in np.arange(hist.shape[1]):
        for R in np.arange(hist.shape[2]):
            r = 'R=' + str(R*32).zfill(3) + '-' + str((R+1)*32-1).zfill(3)
            g = 'G=' + str(G*32).zfill(3) + '-' + str((G+1)*32-1).zfill(3)
            b = 'B=' + str(B*32).zfill(3) + '-' + str((B+1)*32-1).zfill(3)
            print('(' + r +  ', ' + g + ', ' + b + '): ', int(hist[B, G, R]))
```

```
(R=000-031, G=000-031, B=000-031):  1
(R=032-063, G=000-031, B=000-031):  1
(R=064-095, G=000-031, B=000-031):  1
[... 506 more lines ...]
(R=160-191, G=224-255, B=224-255):  1
(R=192-223, G=224-255, B=224-255):  1
(R=224-255, G=224-255, B=224-255):  1
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great.. This is the one that i wanted thank you so much ^^

Comment: ``print('(' + r +  ', ' + g + ', ' + b + '): ', int(hist[B, G, R]))``. I thinks for this part should change to this

Comment: @pingxiu Yes, you're right. I'll fix that in my answer. Thanks!